# Error Message Trying To Use The Print Function After Using A For Loop - Total Newbie

Tags: for-loop

This is now happening everytime I use the print function at the end of any for loop

I keep getting the same error message over and over.

```
>>> mylist = [5,10,15,20]
>>> total = 0
>>> for i in range (0,len(mylist)):
          total = total + mylist[i]
print(total)
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The error message just highlights the p in print(total) (final line of the code). I'm using the IDLE Shell 3.9.2. Has there been an update to the software? Am I doing something wrong? If I indent the final line of code to align with total = total + mylist[i], it's the only way I can get the print function to actually work. The problem is it prints as part of the for loop and I don't want it to print out 4 different outputs. I just want it to print out the sum of all the integers in the mylist variable once, which should be 50. Any help with this basic problem would be great. Also tell me how to leave a positive review and I will.

Comment: Am I right in thinking you can't put a print statement at the end of a for loop in the IDLE shell? In the shell, do you have to invoke the Python promt and then execute the print statement after the for loop?

Comment: I changed the tag Ken

Answer (score 0):

```
Try:
mylist = [5,10,15,20]
total = 0
For i in range (0,len(mylist)):
          total = total + mylist[i]
          print(total)

It will print the values.
```

Comment: I just want it to print 1 value though (not 4 different values). The 1 value I want to print is the sum of all the numbers in mylist, which is 50. Do you know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

mylist = [5,10,15,20]

total = 0

For i in mylist:

```
      total = total + i
```

print(total)

It will print the values. And give you required value 50.
Just dont run these lines on python shell directly create an python file and add above code in it and run that python file.

Comment: Just remove blank spaces between each line and add this code.